# Smoke simulation set to outflow, the smoke still interact with the ceiling

Tags: mantaflow

I set the flow type to outflow, it's supposed to be not interacting with the ceiling as the Blender Manual says, the ceiling will be acting like a black hole, however, below is my screen shot and I can observe the ceiling is colliding with the smoke, why is that thankyou !

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file....the screenshot doesn't help at all in this case

Comment: @Chris I posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, I do not know if this is the intended design, everytime I change the setting of the flow, I need to re-select the "replay" item to make it valid as shown below,
[image]

The issue I came accross resulted from the cache from the previous settings not freed up until I re-select the "replay", so this is my solution.

Comment: The cache type _Replay_ is kind of a "on the fly" simulation, and sometimes can be screwed up if the cache isn't freed correctly. I usually don't simulate with _Replay_ because if I set a little more than the default domain resolution it becomes too slow in my viewport. But that's of course dependent on your hardware. I prefer _Modular_ or _All_ and maybe enable _Is Resumable_. Then I can hit "Bake" or "Free" to simulate or get rid of a simulation. Just for testing and checking settings it doesn't even take long if you're still on a lower resolution.